Proving that the Laplace mechanism satisfies $\rho = \frac{1}{\lambda} + e^\frac{-1}{\lambda} -1$ zero concentrated DP
Mironov 2017 (Table II) showed that the Laplace mechanism with scale parameter $\lambda$ satisfies Renyi DP:
$D_{\alpha}\left( f(D) \lVert f(D') \right) = \frac{1}{\alpha - 1} log\left(\frac{\alpha}{2\alpha - 1}exp\left(\frac{\alpha - 1}{\lambda}\right) + \frac{\alpha - 1}{2 \alpha -1} exp\left( -\frac{\alpha}{\lambda} \right) \right)$ for $\alpha > 1$ and $\frac{1}{\lambda} + exp\left(-\frac{1}{\lambda}\right) - 1$ for $\alpha = 1$.
A mechanism $f$ satisfies $\rho$-zero concentrated DP (zCDP) if
$D_\alpha\left(f(D) \lVert f(D')\right) \le \rho \alpha$ for all $\alpha \in (1, \inf)$.
It appears to be the case that $\frac{D_\alpha}{\alpha}$ in the range $(1, \inf)$ is always maximized at the boundary of $\alpha = 1$ (therefore arriving at the result in the title), but I am having trouble proving it.
I believe it suffices to show that:

The first derivative of the divergence with respect to $\alpha$ at $\alpha=1$ is less than the KL-divergence ($D_1$)
The second derivative of the divergence with respect to $\alpha$ at $\alpha=1$ is less than 0
The divergence is concave down i.e. the second derivative is never positive

It is perhaps feasible for me to show all three for some select values of $\lambda$, but not for all $\lambda > 0$, as the equations for the first and second derivate get pretty complicated.

Note this question is inspired from the following tweet thread: https://twitter.com/yuxiangw_cs/status/1565765510872018950
